# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: While connecting to rally through rally rest api in java

Tags: api, rest, rally

I am trying to connect to rally through rally rest api for fetching a user. I am facing IO Exception while connecting to the rally URL https://rally1.rallydev.com.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to connect to Rally using [Rally REST toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava):

```
String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
String apiKey = "_abc123";
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
```

where `_abc123` is a placeholder for a valid [ApiKey](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager).

ApiKeys and Rally authentication is general (Rally username/password) cannot be used with your company's SSO. If your organization is using SSO to connect to Rally, and if your SSO configuration allows exceptions, your username has to be added to the exceptions list. If a user account is on the SSO exceptions list it can be used to connect to Rally using Rally authentication (username/password or ApiKey).